# Return list containing the first two strings in the list as a tuple

Tags: string, list, haskell, greedy

I am writing a Haskell function that takes a list of strings and returns a list containing the first two strings as a tuple as the result. So an example output would be:

```
listtuple ["bride", "zilla", "crazy", "women"] = [("bride", "villa")]
listtuple ["basketball", "football"] = [("basketball", "football")]
```

The way I was thinking of approaching it like so:

```
listtuple :: Eq a => [Str a] -> [(Str a, Str a)]
listtuple xs = [(x,y) | x <- xs !! 0, y <- xs !! 1]
```

Essentially I figured that I could just just pick the elements in the first and second indices of the list but I'm getting errors. Any help here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you probably wanted to do was this:

```
listtuple xs =
    let x = xs !! 0
        y = xs !! 1
     in (x, y)
```

Note that this is NOT the same thing as what you wrote.  The reason is that the list comprehension you wrote translates into the following:

```
do x <- xs !! 0  -- Treat the first  element of xs as a list
   y <- xs !! 1  -- Treat the second element of xs as a list
   return (x, y)
```

This illustrates the issue: You are treating `xs !! 0` and `xs !! 1` as lists when they are not lists.  `xs !! 0` is just a single element, so if you want to declare that `x` is equal to `xs !! 0`, you use:

```
let x = xs !! 0
 in <some expression that uses x>
```

The `<-` in list comprehension syntax does not do the same thing and I recommend you steer clear of list comprehensions until you understand how the list monad works, because the compiler translates list comprehensions to the list monad.

Now, the second problem is that you use `(!!)`.  You should steer clear of partial functions like `(!!)` and focus on using pattern matching to solve these things.  The idiomatic way to do what you request would be to pattern match on the first two elements:

```
listtuple (x:y:_) = (x, y)
```

... EXCEPT that will fail on lists that contain less than two elements.  You guard against this by storing the result as a `Maybe`, where a `Just` wraps a successful result, and `Nothing` indicates failure:

```
listtuple :: [a] -> Maybe (a, a)
listtuple (x:y:_) = Just (x, y)
listtuple _       = Nothing
```

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer would be

```
listtuple :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
listtuple (x:y:_) = [(x,y)]
listtuple _ = []
```

Since your list will always contain one item or none, so it is better to use `Maybe` which exactly servers this purpose.

```
listtuple2 :: [a] -> Maybe (a,a)
listtuple2 (x:y:_) = Just (x,y)
listtuple2 _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code that I can see, but if you have a specific question about why your code doesn't work please let me know.

First of all, the type signature that you provided is invalid. `String` is a parameterless data structure, `Str a` is nothing, unless of course you've defined a data structure named `Str` yourself. A list of `String`s will not need the equality constraint that you provided either, as the compiler already knows that `String` is an instance of `Eq`.

Secondly, you are using list comprehension syntax in (what looks like) the place of a where clause. Consider that Haskell will attempt to evaluate `xs !! 0` before binding the element `x`. Because this a list comprehension, this might not fail immediately because `xs` is a list of `String`s (which are actually lists of `Char`), but you would end up with tuples of `Char`s pulled from the first and second strings within xs.

Here is a simple solution using pattern matching that produces what you want.

```
listtuple :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
listtuple (x:y:zs) = [(x, y)]
```

Note that this isn't a total function (ie, it will result in an error if you pass it a list with fewer than two elements). This could be made total by perhaps returning the empty list when an empty or one element list is passed to it, would that work for your intended purpose?

Here's an alternate version that you might find fits the mental model you used to write your own version.

```
listtuple xs = [(x, y)]
            where
                x = xs !! 0
                y = xs !! 1
```